# Does importing a material component import the whole library?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Does importing a material component import the whole library ?

with this code:

```
import { someComponent } from '@angular/material';
```

I mean when webpack builds and bundles my project does it download the whole material project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code , **`Material Design`** for angular is structured/modularized in such a way that it can be imported separately for each component. so it is normal to import features by per a module.

```
import { MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';
```

the above will import only necessary files related to toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

When you write like

```
import * from '@angular/material';
```

Than it's import all library of material but when you write like

```
import { someComponent } from '@angular/material';
```

it's import only someComponent from material